# after 3 variants i can't add another variant of product in shopify

Tags: shopify

i have Shopify Basic Plan purchased.
Im Not Able to Adding More Variant after Adding Default 3 Variants.

**3 Variant is Shopify's default added (In Below Image)**

**4th Variant : Thickness Option = 14 Pt. Cardstock, 16 pt. Premium, 18 pt. Ultrapremium,**

**5th Variant : Folding Option = Unfolded, Half Fold (2 Panel), Trifold (3 Panel)**

please help me with this, how can i add more variants?

[image]

Like below image I want.. variants

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to say, product options. In Shopify, you can have up to 2000 variants now, but you only get 3 options. The way 99% of people deal with this, is they try and eliminate any option that is not directly altering price. Collect the values of any of those options using line item properties. So it is really a bit of soul searching exercise in some cases, if you really really believe you need more than 3 options and they all affect pricing and inventory.